# Asp.net core razor pages select with enumeration

Tags: asp.net-core, select, razor

I am populating a selectlist containing various pre-defined intervals (one week, one month etc.) from an enumeration:

```
            <select asp-for="SelIntvl" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<KPI.PresetIntervals>()">
            </select>
```

When the page loads, I can set 'SelIntvl' in the code behind and the page will show the selected interval as expected.

```
 public void OnGet(string startDate, string endDate)
 {
            ...
                SelIntvl = KPI.PresetIntervals.PastSixMonths;
            ...
 }
```

When the user enters a start date and an end date, the dates are applied via an input button:

```
            <p>
                @*<input type="submit" value="Apply" />*@
                <button class="btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Apply</button>
            </p>
```

In case a start data and an end date have been specified by the user, I am setting 'SelIntvl' to 'Custom' in the code behind:

```
       else if (startDate != null && endDate != null) // if user specified start and end date, set the interval to 'custom'
        {
            SelIntvl = KPI.PresetIntervals.Custom;
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
        }
```

However, this time, on the page the selected option is not updated properly to 'Custom' but shows the previously selected interval. Why is that? How can I get the selection list to display the correct selection? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public enum PresetIntervals
{
    None = 0,
    Custom = 1,
    PastSixMonths = 2,
}
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel

<form>
    <div>
        StartDate:<input asp-for="StartDate" name="startDate" />
    </div>
    <div>
        EndDate:<input asp-for="EndDate" name="endDate" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelIntvl" class="control-label"></label>

        <select asp-for="SelIntvl" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<PresetIntervals>()"></select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

Privacy.cshtml.cs:

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    public PresetIntervals SelIntvl { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        if(startDate == null && endDate == null)
        {
            SelIntvl = PresetIntervals.PastSixMonths;

        }
        if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
        {
            SelIntvl = PresetIntervals.Custom;
            StartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
            EndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

If still does not work in your project,you could also try `ModelState.Clear()` to reset the value:

```
if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    SelIntvl = PresetIntervals.Custom;
    StartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
    EndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
}
```

Comment: It worked when I added ModelState.Clear! Many thanks!